# Mysql query returning null value and 0 results

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

i have an issue that is driving me crazy!

```
    query = "SELECT Formula  FROM filterPrice where idCode='" & txtCodigo.Text & "' and (FilterData<='" & cant & "')"
Dim selectCommand As New MySqlCommand(query, Conexion.conn)

        priceSelected = Conversions.ToString(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar())
        Conexion.Desconecta()
        Conexion.conn.Dispose()
```

but this return nothing, any hint?

Comment: if i delete all after AND it Works fie and returns a value, but i dunno why the complete query doesnt work

Comment: Please refer [SQL Injection] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) first

Comment: Did you try and use breakpoint to check if you are correct values or not to query and you have related data in db ? any specific error

Comment: there is no error, just gives nothing, the variable priceselected keeps empty

Comment: as i mentioned, if i just use query = "SELECT Formula  FROM filterPrice where idCode='" & txtCodigo.Text & "'"Dim selectCommand As New MySqlCommand(query, Conexion.conn)

        priceSelected = Conversions.ToString(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar())
        Conexion.Desconecta()     this gives me a vaule, but if i try to add the and and the other condition it doesnt produce a value

Comment: Add a Console.WriteLine(query) just before creating the command and add the resulting text in your output window to your question above.

Comment: Try this, same query but changed for security :

query = "SELECT Formula  FROM filterPrice where idCode=@IdCode and (FilterData<=@Cant)"
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCode", txtCodigo.Text)
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cant", cant)
Dim selectCommand As New MySqlCommand(query, Conexion.conn)
priceSelected = Conversions.ToString(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar())
Conexion.Desconecta()
Conexion.conn.Dispose()

If you have a valid data, then the query should work. Btw what's datatype for `Cant` ?

Comment: what's a datatype for FilterData column in table?

Comment: btw query is a string variable too

Comment: Thats just great. Use query as `Command`

Comment: I think your query should be like this   `query = "SELECT Formula  FROM filterPrice where idCode='" & txtCodigo.Text & "' and (FilterData like %'" & cant & "'%)"`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'11'%)' at line 1

Comment: @SankarRaj : Its just a suggestion, but kindly use `Parameterised queries` or `Stored Procedures` for security and better performance.

Comment: @Mahadev yeah sure its a great idea...

Comment: It is so difficult to add  the values of the variables used in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a detailed example for Data retrieval using Parameterised queries :

```
Dim con as new MySQLConnection("Data Source=<server name>;Initial Catalog=<Db Name>; Integrated Security=True;")
Dim cmdSelectData as new MySQLCommand("SELECT Formula  FROM filterPrice where idCode=@IdCode and FilterData<=@Cant", con)
cmdSelectData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCode", txtCodigo.Text)
cmdSelectData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cant", cant)
If not con.State=ConnectionState.Open then con.open()
priceSelected=cmdSelectData.ExecuteScalar()
con.Close()
```

This is a more secure way with databases. Hope it helps.